# macOS terminal fails to login

Tags: macos-catalina

After installing macOS Big Sur beta my terminal behaves weirdly.

If I start terminal after PC restart I can start terminal just fine, however if I close it and try to start again I find myself at blank terminal saying "login".

I get the same problem with iTerm and native Terminal.

[image: Terminal preview]

Comment: I've got the exact same issue, both with the native terminal and iTerm. At the beginning I thought it was a problem with my setup rather than macOS Big Sur, I guess we'll have to file a radar to Apple.

Comment: it is a iTerm issue. if you dont run iTerm at all in macos 11.0 you wont have this problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm having this issue as well.

[This discussion](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/649941) from the Apple Developer Forums explains the issue and the solution.

> Found the trigger, it's an iTerm2 thing.
>
> Disable Enable session restoration under Preferences > Advanced > Session, after that you shouldn't have a problem.
>
> Raised an issue with iTerm's developers. Not sure if there's something here on the OS side as well.

Comment: absolutely unrelated to iTerm, it happens in regular Terminal too

Comment: @otrejni If you read the discussion I linked in my answer, you'll see that the issue is caused by iTerm but effects both iTerm and Terminal.

Comment: I was having this same issue, not on Big Sur but on Mojave (10.14.6). I have no idea what the cause was (I've never even heard of iTerm so I assume I don't have it installed), but restarting my machine fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue on Mojave as well, both on iTerm and Terminal. The solution was to restart my machine.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem after a securiry upgrade on macOS Ventura

Restarting the machine solved the problem